# add “actions” while posting to a feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am able to post to a users feed using a URL from my app, for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?
link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!
```

According to the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ it is possible to add "actions" which appear next to the Like and Comment buttons under each post. The documentation states the actions must be in a JSON format with object with keys name and link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could add actions parameter. If in PHP then you could do like:

```
   'actions' => json_encode( array(
     'name' => 'Some sample link example',
     'link' => 'http://something.com/test/'
    )),
```

Did you mean something like that.

Hope it helps